# Weblogic Datasource pool permission issue (Intermittent)

Tags: spring, weblogic, datasource, quartz-scheduler, jndi

We have this spring based java web application where our datasources are defined as JNDIs and the application is deployed on Weblogic Application Server.

We have some spring quartz jobs which run frequently, and access these datasources for DB connection. We are getting below given error in app server for pool permission. And the weird thing is that it happens intermittently so it works fine sometimes and fails with this error other times.

Most of the sites I looked for have solution to this as some configs changes .. but my issue is those configs are already there and most importantly it does not throw any error most of the times. But it is important to work each time because jobs are set to work only once a day.

Please put across if any further details are needed.

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: weblogic.jdbc.extensions.PoolPermissionsSQLException: weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePermissionsException: User \"anonymous\" does not have permission to perform operation \"reserve\" on resource \"XXX_YYY\" of module \"none\" of application \"none\" of type \"ConnectionPool\" Error Code: 0 Call: BEGIN AAA.BBB(p_recordset=>?, p_type=>?); END;  bind => [2 parameters bound] Query: ReadAllQuery(name=\"getSSS\" referenceClass=WxyzAbc )
```

Comment: Do you have some sort of cluster set up on the DB (multiple nodes) and for some reason permissions not matching on all of those?

Comment: Hi JoseK, Thanks for your reply. Yes we do have cluster set up. However I doubt if the issue is at DB level. Error seems to be at Datasource permission on weblogic, as the `resource \"XXX_YYY\"` is the name of the persistence unit in JPA's persistence.xml. Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: anyone? anything plz ? :)